# Context Switching using swap context() and a custom yield function

Tags: c, multithreading

I am writing my own user level thread library and am running into some issues. Below is the code of the library I have written thus far after the edits provided by you guys and also some introspection from my end:

```
struct tcb {
    int thread_id;
    int thread_pri;
    ucontext_t thread_context;
    struct tcb *next;
} *ready_head;

typedef struct tcb tcb;

tcb *running_head;
tcb *tmp,*tmp1,*tmp2,*temp;
// ucontext_t *ready;

// head = NULL;
// running_head = head;

void t_shutdown()
{
    free(temp);
    free(tmp);
    free(tmp1);
    free(ready_head);
    free(running_head);
}

void t_yield()
{
   // tmp2 = ready_head; 
    tmp1 = running_head;

/*  tmp = running_head;
  running_head = ready_head;
    while(tmp1->next != NULL)
       tmp1 = tmp1->next;

    tmp1->next = tmp;
*/
    insert(tmp1);
    running_head = ready_head;
    ready_head = ready_head->next;
    printf("yield1\n");
    swapcontext(&running_head->thread_context, &tmp1->thread_context);
    printf("yield2\n");   
   //   setcontext(&ready_head->thread_context);    
}

void insert(tcb *a)
{
    tcb *b;

    if (ready_head == NULL)
    {
        ready_head = a;
    }
    else
    {
        b = ready_head;
        while(b->next)
            b = b->next;

        b->next = a;

    }
   printf("insert\n");
}

void t_init()
{
    tmp = (tcb *)malloc(sizeof(tcb));

  getcontext(&tmp->thread_context);    /* let tmp be the context of main() */

    tmp->next = NULL;
    running_head = tmp;
    ready_head = NULL;
}

int t_create(void (*fct)(int), int id, int pri)
{
  size_t sz = 0x10000;

  temp = (tcb *)malloc(sizeof(tcb));

  getcontext(&temp->thread_context);

  temp->thread_id = id;
  temp->thread_pri = pri;

  temp->thread_context.uc_stack.ss_sp = malloc(sz);  /* new statement */
  temp->thread_context.uc_stack.ss_size = sz;
  temp->thread_context.uc_stack.ss_flags = 0;
  temp->thread_context.uc_link = &tmp->thread_context;
  makecontext(&temp->thread_context, fct, 1, id);
    insert(temp);
  printf("1\n"); 
}
```

I am testing this library on the following test program:

```
void assign(void)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("in assign(1): %d\n", i);

  t_yield();

  for (i = 10; i < 13; i++)
    printf("in assign(2): %d\n", i);

  t_yield();

  for (i = 20; i < 23; i++)
    printf("in assign(3): %d\n", i);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  t_init();
  t_create(assign, 1, 1);

  printf("in main(): 0\n");

  t_yield();

  printf("in main(): 1\n");
  t_yield();

  printf("in main(): 2\n");
  t_yield();

  printf("done...\n");

  return (0);
}
```

The expected output is:

```
in main(): 0
in assign(1): 0
in assign(1): 1
in assign(1): 2
in main(): 1
in assign(2): 10
in assign(2): 11
in assign(2): 12
in main(): 2
in assign(3): 20
in assign(3): 21
in assign(3): 22
done...
```

However, I am getting:

```
in main(): 0
in main(): 1
in main(): 2
done...
```

I now know that there is an issue with the swapcontext() as that does not seem to be working at all. I have tried to use printf statements to debug my program but am still unable to get this to work! Please help ....

Comment: For starters, you're never setting `next` pointers `NULL`.  This doesn't happen by magic.

Comment: ok i spotted that now .... thanks to you .... is there anything else that you see that might be causing this problem?

Comment: Actually I just ran the program again and noticed that I had posted some code earlier which I had modified but not saved. The edit to the code is the one that produces the output I have mentioned in contrast to the expected output. Also, the initialization of the NULL value to the pointers is not so much of a problem, because the first thing that the program does when it runs is call t_init which init's the pointer values ....

Comment: Please read what I wrote. Nowhere in `t_init` or `t_create` is there the code `tmp->next = NULL` or `temp->next = NULL` (your choice of variable names is terrible by the way). Without setting these pointers null, the loop in `yield` intended to find the end of the list has undefined behavior.

Comment: @Gene I did it now in my code, and the output remains the same. I have now set these pointers to NULL in both the init() and the create() functions. Are you able to spot anything else that I am unable to spot?

Comment: You had better read up on how linked lists work.  Most of your code that manipulates the ready and running lists is broken.

Comment: @Gene Thanks! I did brush up my linked lists and have modified my code. Can you please take a look and help me fix the swapcontext() issue?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that in your `t_yield()` function you are actually swapping the `ready_head` context with the `ready_head` context. You might want to try

`swapcontext(&tmp->thread_context, &running_head->thread_context);`

instead.

Comment: Could you please tell me which part of the yield() function is doing this? I had a feeling there is a problem with the yield() function. But I am unable to spot where the problem is .... appreciate your help!

Comment: @user2784743 After the line `running_head = ready_head;`, `running_head` and `ready_head` point to the same tcb.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! However, when I do change it the way you said, the output comes out to be : in main(): 0
in assign(1): 0
in assign(1): 1
in assign(1): 2
in assign(2): 10
in assign(2): 11
in assign(2): 12

Comment: Could you please take a look at the revised code I posted and let me know why my swapcontext() does not seem to switch over the context?